# React binding events within a function

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass in arguments into an onClick function, but it keeps firing on return. I believe I need to bind the click handler, but I am not exactly sure how to do that.

```js
function (phone_calls, right_side, before_children) {

   
   function test (blah){
  console.log(blah)
    }




  return boxy(
    "Phone Calls",

    _.map(phone_calls, function(a) {



   return d("div.splitter-wrap", {onClick: test("testarg")}, [
     d("table.splitter", { className: name}, d("tr", 
    [d('td',a.date),d('td',a.number)]
      ))
   ]);
}),
```

Comment: What is this my friend ?   spiral function !

Comment: Yeah... Trying to bind the onclick to the test function so ti wont fire on return

Comment: Try to call the callback function this way ````this.test.bind(this, 'testarg')````.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an arrow function, like:

```
{ onClick: ()=> { test("testarg") } }
```

otherwise you can use bind such as:

```
{ onClick: test.bind(this, "testarg") }
```

but that is more verbose and has the (potentially) unwanted side-effect of setting `this`.